# Why does $[\sigma_{\mu\nu\rho\tau}]=\frac13(R_{\rho\mu\nu\tau}+R_{\tau\mu\nu\rho})$ imply that $[\sigma^i{}_i{}^k{}_k]=-\frac23R$?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, curvature, mathematics

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold and $\sigma$ the world function. From page $197$ of Fulling's [Aspects of Quantum Field Theory in Curved Spacetime](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781139172073):

> $[\sigma_{\mu\nu\rho\tau}]=\frac13(R_{\rho\mu\nu\tau}+R_{\tau\mu\nu\rho})$ so that $[\sigma^i{}_i{}^k{}_k]=-\frac23R$.

I tried to verify this statement, but according to my calculation the second equation is only true up to an additional term:

I assume that $\sigma^i{}_i=g^{ij}(\partial_i\partial_j\sigma-\Gamma^k{}_{ij}\partial_k\sigma)=\Box\sigma$ such that the product rule for the Laplacian yields
$$\sigma^i{}_i{}^k{}_k=\Box\Box\sigma=\Box(g^{ij}\sigma_{ij})=\Box (g^{ij})\sigma_{ij}+g^{ij}\Box(\sigma_{ij})+2\langle\mathrm{d}(g^{ij}),\mathrm{d}(\sigma_{ij})\rangle$$
The coincidence limit of the third term in Riemannian coordinates vanishes and as Mike pointed out we have$^1$
$$[g^{ij}\Box\sigma_{ij}]=-\frac23 R,$$
but the coincidence limit of $\Box(g^{ij})\sigma_{ij}$ is non-zero and hence I get an additional term, don't I?

---

$^1$ Since $g^{ij}\Box(\sigma_{ij})=g^{ij}g^{kl}\sigma_{ijkl}$ this follows from the assumption that
$$[\sigma_{ijkl}]=\frac13(R_{kijl}+R_{lijk})$$
with $R_{ijkl}:=g(e_i,R(e_k,e_l)e_j)$.

Comment: *AFAIU this is not the 4th partial derivative.* It’s the 4th *covariant* derivative of $\sigma(x,x’)$ with respect to $x$.

Comment: The link to the Fulling book is invalid.

Comment: Why do the indices change from Greek to Roman?

Comment: @Ghoster "The link to the Fulling book is invalid." - I copied the DOI from [the official website](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/aspects-of-quantum-field-theory-in-curved-spacetime/D96D902C0432D20FA5F0CC75C5E93FE6), but you are right that the link does not work. I am replacing the link.

Comment: @Ghoster "Why do the indices change from Greek to Roman?" - The reason is a bit complicated: To be precise, the author writes the following: " $[\sigma_{jklm}]$ can be expressed in terms of Riemann tensors $(8.34)$ so that..." - I thought that it would be more convenient for the reader if I insert $(8.34)$.

Comment: @Ghoster "It’s the 4th covariant derivative" - Could you please elaborate? I thought that $\sigma_{ij}$ is a short notation for $(A\sigma)_{ij}$, where $A$ is an operator that maps scalars to $2$-tensors (the composition of the differential with the covariant derivative induced by the Levi Civita connection). Do you agree?

Comment: You have a much more abstract approach to differential geometry than I do, and I don’t know whether what you asked regarding this operator $A$ is true or false. From my point of view, $\sigma_{ij}$ is simply shorthand for $\sigma_{;ij}$, where the semicolon indicates covariant differentiation. I have done these HaMiDeW calculations (but without gauge fields) and that’s all there is to it.

Comment: As you can tell, I am used to doing differential-geometric calculations using only component notation. This is old-fashioned but it works and is straightforward. You don’t need to think about operators, maps, composition, or differentials to do these calculations. Weinberg wrote an entire textbook on GR using the component approach.

Answer (score 1):

Just raise and contract the indices on the Riemann tensors to get the scalar curvature:
$$
R= {R^{ij}}_{ij}
$$

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145692/discussion-on-answer-by-mike-stone-why-does-sigma-mu-nu-rho-tau-frac13r); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Sorry for the many comments. Unfortunately I still believe that something is off. I edited my question to explain why $\sigma^i{}_i{}^k{}_k\neq g^{ij}(\sigma_{ij}{}^k{}_k)$.